# ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig | cordova-plugin-purchase build fails

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I'm really stuck with the cordova in app plugin..

I get the following error when i build the iOS app:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC build/roma16.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/roma16.build/Objects-normal/i386/InAppPurchase.o roma16/Plugins/cc.fovea.cord
ova.purchase/InAppPurchase.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma
16/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,roma16.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,roma16,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimul
ator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECO
MPS_DIR=/Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/cordova/build
-debug.xcconfig,-project,roma16.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,roma16,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CO
NFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/patrickhofer/Do
cuments/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I also got this one before:

```
In file included from /Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/roma16/Plugins/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase/InAppPurchase.m:

9:
/Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/roma16/Plugins/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase/InAppPurchase.h:13:9: fatal error: 'Co
rdova/NSData+Base64.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/NSData+Base64.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

And i think this is strange as well:

```
In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/patrickhofer/Documents/Apps/roma16/platforms/ios/roma16/Plugins/cordova-plugin-globalizatio
n/CDVGlobalization.h:20:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Fram
eworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCalendar.h:69:2: note: 'NSMinuteCalendarUnit' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        NSMinuteCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitMinute instead") = NSCalendarUnitMin
ute,
        ^
```

Here is what i did before:

> ionic plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.purchase  --variable BILLING_KEY="XXX"

and i added the logic in my app:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if((window.device && device.platform == "iOS") && window.storekit) {
    storekit.init({
        debug:    true,
        ready:    onReady,
        purchase: onPurchase,
        restore:  onRestore,
        error:    onError
    });
}
var onReady = function() { }
var onPurchase = function(transactionId, productId, receipt) { }
var onRestore = function(transactionId, productId, transactionReceipt) { }
var onError = function(errorCode, errorMessage) { }

if((window.device && device.platform == "iOS") && window.storekit) {
                storekit.init({
                    debug:    true,
                    ready:    function() {
                        storekit.load(["unlockall"], function (products, invalidIds) {
                            console.log("In-app purchases are ready to go");
                        });
                    },
                    purchase: function(transactionId, productId, receipt) {
                        if(productId === 'unlockall') {
                            console.log("Purchased product id 1");
                        }
                    },
                    restore:  function(transactionId, productId, transactionReceipt) {
                        if(productId === 'unlockall') {
                            console.log("Restored product id 1 purchase")
                        }
                    },
                    error:    function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
                        console.log("ERROR: " + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
            }
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
              // for form inputs)
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

              // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
              // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
              // a much nicer keyboard experience.
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
          });
      });
```

Any help much appreciated! I'm going crazy...

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long time as well. This solution worked for me:

1. remove your cordova-plugin-purchase plugin
2. reinstall, cordova plugin
   add https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/403